# One domain name two sites on two servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, lamp, domain-registration

This may have been answered already but i couldn't find it.
I am just a plain ole C# developer, my boss handed me this project said Get R Done so thats what i am trying to do.

We have one domain clientssiteaspnet.com.
It is a .Net site has a complicated search mechanism using a SQL Server DB, its on Server2003.
The client wanted a blog, they built one at clientssiteaspnet.com/blog using [BlogEngine.Net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)
So now the client wants his blog on WordPress because BlogEngine.Net is driving him crazy.

So WordPress works best on a LAMP environment and that is where i want to put it.
clientssiteaspnet.com works best on Windows Server because it is a .Net site with a SQL Server Database.

So my question is how do i go about getting the one domain name on two different servers at 2 different hosting company's. So i can keep the .Net site where it is now and at my new LAMP environment i have the clientssiteaspnet.com/blog site.

I am really new to this because i really just like writing code all day, but its a problem that i must solve.

Any links to articles, tutorials, blogs and all other types of information on things i need to educate myself about to accomplish this task would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Edit: I realize i could run WAMP and IIS server simultaneously on the Windows Server, but i am trying to avoid that kind of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a subdomain for the blog.  For example, the main site on

clientsiteaspnet.com

and the blog on

blog.clientsiteaspnet.com

If that's not acceptable, then you could use a reverse proxy to "map" the blog server into the  main site.

For example, clientsiteaspnet.com points to a reverse proxy (possibly a separate system, or you could put it on one of the web servers) and the reverse proxy talks "behind the scenes" to both servers, acting as a middle man.  This lets you say that the root of the site is on server A, but /blog/ is on server B, and is transparent to the client.

This is obviously more complicated than the first option.

--update--

I haven't worked with IIS in years, so I can't offer much help there.  I believe you'll need Microsoft ISA server.  With Apache, you just need mod_proxy.

On the blog server, you shouldn't need to do much.  If you're not doing link rewriting in the reverse proxy, you'll need to make sure the links on the blog server point to the proxy rather than directly to the log server.

For example, if the reverse proxy is at clientsiteaspnet.com and the client uses clientsiteaspnet.com/blog to access the blog, then the links in the blog software need to be

clientsiteaspnet.com/blog/add_comment instead of serverb.com/blog/add_comment

Because you want the traffic to go through the reverse proxy in order to provide the illusion that it's all one site.

Comment: ok a reverse proxy in IIS on our winserver environment. If i use a big box hosting company(DreamHost) for the LAMP site what would be have to done on the /blog end to recognize that Server 1 is talking to it? Could you provide me with some links with some information so i can get a better understanding of how i will accomplish this?

Comment: This was very informative and looks to be much more down the track that i am looking for in my solution.  http://www.seomoz.org/blog/what-is-a-reverse-proxy-and-how-can-it-help-my-seo

Comment: Oh wow, that makes such perfect sense. I will probably move the web application to windows server 2008 and do it in IIS 7 environment. On how to do this, check this link out ! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

Answer (score 1):

How about using blog.clientssiteaspnet.com for the blog instead of clientssiteaspnet.com/blog? Then it's a simple matter of creating a DNS record for blog.clientssiteaspnet.com that resolves to the ip address of the LAMP server.

Comment: We are trying to preserve SEO and i guess that is why i was told we cant do that. Apparently there a lot of inbound links to their blog.

Comment: You can transfer the pagerank by 301 redirecting...

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes but if the site is on two different domains i do not think they will continue to get the SEO benefit of the blog. I may be wrong this not an area of my expertise.

Comment: My understanding is that you are wrong.

Comment: @ceejayoz I said i didnt know this isnt my area of expertise and i am relying mostly on my PM and senior leads opinions to explain this to me. But if you have a link to an article explaining why hosting a site on 2 different domains does not affect SEO. Or better yet an article explaining why moving part of a site to a sub domain does not affect SEO. Than i would have a better understanding ("I stated this is not my area of expertise.").

Comment: @ceejayoz BTW I love being wrong it means i am learning :)